# Can't use import in ES6 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code 1.15 on Windows 10 and playing with ES6 in a `.js` file.

I can import using `require` with no problem:

```
var deepFreeze  = require('deep-freeze'); // works
```

However, `import` does not work.

```
import deepFreeze from 'deep-freeze';
```

The above gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:578:3
```

I've got Node 8.3 installed and am using the following `js.config`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Update: The error above is from running the JS file using the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. But running it with Node also doesn't work.

Comment: Well, does Node 8.3 support ES6 imports? The error message doesn't seem to have anything to do with VSC.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c) article, it seems they are not yet supported. I guess that's the problem then, thanks!